# MySQL: Select rows based on values in already selected rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, union

I want to select rows from a joined table in my database based on values in rows that have already been selected. Basically, if the parent or granparent row is active, also include the child or grandchild rows in the results.

I have attempted using different combinations of `JOINS` and `UNIONS` to get my desired result with no success.

**Here is my example data:**

**Table 1: objectives**
(objectives available for members to set as a goal or complete)

```
id   | name     | parent
---------------------------
A    | Obj A    | null 
A1   | Obj A1   | A 
A2   | Obj A2   | A
A2-1 | Obj A2.1 | A2
B    | Obj B    | null
B1   | Obj B1   | B
B1-1 | Obj B1.1 | B1
C    | Obj C    | null
C1   | Obj C1   | C
C1-1 | Obj C1.1 | C1
```

**Table 2: memberObjectives**
(objectives members have completed or set as a goal)

```
id | objective | member | status
-----------------------------------
1  | A         | 001    | goal
2  | A1        | 001    | complete
3  | C         | 001    | goal
```

**Desired Results:** Join both tables and select all rows where the status is `goal` or `complete` OR where the parent or grandparent objective has a status of `goal` or `complete`.

```
objective | member | name     | status
------------------------------------------
A         | 001    | Obj A    | goal
A1        | 001    | Obj A1   | complete
A2        | 001    | Obj A2   | null
A2-1      | 001    | Obj A2-1 | null
C         | 001    | Obj C    | goal
C1        | 001    | Obj C1   | null
C1-1      | 001    | Obj C1.1 | null
```

`A2` and `C2` are included, because their parents `A` and `C` have a statuses of `goal` and `A2-1` and `C1-1` are included, because they have grandparents with a status of `goal`. `B` and its child and granchild objectives are not included, because there are no `B`’s in the `memberObjectives` table with a status of `complete` or `goal`.

My latest attempt, which I know is not even close is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT mo.objective, mo.member, o.name, mo.status 
  FROM objectives AS o
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM memberObjectives 
    WHERE member = '001') AS mo ON o.id = mo.objective
  LEFT JOIN objectives AS o2 ON o2.id = o.parent
  LEFT JOIN objectives AS o3 ON o3.id = o2.parent 
  GROUP BY o.id
```

Thank you for any help you can offer!

Comment: this would be easy if your ID was numbers instead of A, A1... etc.. are the only ones you want A's? or is that just your example? because you can filter off of the A. the problem is the grandparent is not possible to do with just joins

Comment: @JohnRuddell `A`s are just for the example. I might want to get all `A`s and `C`s that have a `goal` or `complete` status or that have a parent or grandparent with that status, but not any `B`s, because the member has not completed any `B`s or set them as goals.

Comment: I'm currently wondering if there is a way to join the tables, so I end up with two extra columns `parentStatus` and `grandparentStatus`, so that if either of these columns or the original `status` column is `goal` or `complete` include in results. (`WHERE status = 'goal' OR status = 'complete' OR parentStatus = 'goal' OR parentStatus = 'complete' OR grandparentStatus = 'goal' OR grandparentStatus = 'complete'`)

Answer (score 0):

Can't test it but try this:

```
SELECT mo.objective, mo.member, o.name, mo.status 
  FROM objectives AS o
  LEFT JOIN memberObjectives o.id=mo.objetive
WHERE status='goal' or status='complete'
OR o.id IN(select parent from objetives o inner join memberObjectives mo on o.parent=mo.objetive WHERE status='goal' or status='complete')
```

This should give you the record with the status goal or complete and the records whos parent has that. I'ts up to you extendit to gran-father. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! It didn't like the fact that `objectives AS o` was not unique the second time it was called. I fixed some typos and gave the second call to `objectives` a unique alias. Now it says, `#1054 - Unknown column 'mo.objective' in 'on clause'`. Here is the current query: `SELECT mo.objective, mo.member, o.name, mo.status FROM objectives AS o LEFT JOIN memberObjectives AS mo ON o.id=mo.objetive WHERE status='goal' or status='complete'
OR o.id IN(select parent from objectives o2 inner join memberObjectives mo2 on o2.parent=mo.objective WHERE status='goal' or status='complete')`

Comment: this only returns the two rows that have GOAL and COMPLETE.. it doesn't add the child and grandchild.

Answer (score 0):

Three queries for you to look at: see [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3aca/65) for working example

IF you can filter by the id being an A then this query will do exactly what you want.

```
SELECT t.id as objective, mo.member, t.name, mo.status from(
  SELECT * FROM objective o
)AS t
LEFT JOIN memberObjective mo ON mo.objective = t.id
WHERE t.id in(SELECT objective FROM memberObjective)
OR t.parent in(SELECT o.id FROM objective o where o.id like "%A%")
```

This query gets the parent, but not the grandparent.

```
SELECT t.id as objective, mo.member, t.name, mo.status from(
  SELECT * FROM objective o
)AS t
LEFT JOIN memberObjective mo ON mo.objective = t.id
WHERE t.id in(SELECT objective FROM memberObjective)
OR t.parent in(SELECT o.id FROM objective o join memberObjective mo on mo.objective = o.id)
```

this query gets the parent and grandparent but it doesn't filter out the B's.. there is not enough data in the database to get to add the grandparent since A2 appears only twice in your tables and its for the parent and id.

```
SELECT t.id as objective, mo.member, t.name, mo.status from(
  SELECT * FROM objective o
)AS t
LEFT JOIN memberObjective mo ON mo.objective = t.id
WHERE t.id in(SELECT objective FROM memberObjective)
OR t.parent in(SELECT o.id FROM objective o left join memberObjective mo on mo.objective = o.id) 
----  you could add LIMIT 4 to get the correct results but thats another semi hacky way to do it
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We're getting closer and I'm learning some new stuff. Looking at the FIDDLE, the only query that is getting the desired results is the first, but that is, because it is looking for `A`s. The solution needs to be based on `status` equaling `goal` or `complete` for itself, its parent, or its grandparent. I updated the question with `C` objectives to better show the desired results.Thanks again for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

I created a solution that seems to be working for now. It adds a few more joins to include a `parentStatus` and `grandparentStatus` column to each row. Now if the `status`, `parentStatus`, or `grandparentStatus` is `goal` or `complete` the row is included in the results.

**The results of the MySQL query below would be as follows:**

```
objective | member | name     | status    | parentStatus | grandparentStatus
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A         | 001    | Obj A    | goal      | null         | null
A1        | 001    | Obj A1   | complete  | goal         | null
A2        | 001    | Obj A2   | null      | goal         | null
A2-1      | 001    | Obj A2-1 | null      | null         | goal
C         | 001    | Obj C    | goal      | null         | null
C1        | 001    | Obj C1   | null      | goal         | null
C1-1      | 001    | Obj C1.1 | null      | null         | goal
```

**Here is the MySQL query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM objectives AS o  
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM memberObjectives WHERE member = '001') 
    AS mo ON mo.objective = o.id 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT mo2.status AS parentStatus, mo2.objective AS parentObjective
    FROM memberObjectives AS mo2
    LEFT JOIN objectives AS o2 ON o2.parent = mo2.objective 
    WHERE mo2.member = '001') 
      AS parent ON parent.parentObjective = o.parent
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT mo3.status AS grandparentStatus, mo3.objective AS grandparentObjective 
    FROM memberObjectives AS mo3
    LEFT JOIN objectives AS o3 ON o3.parent = mo3.objective 
    WHERE mo3.member = '001') 
      AS grandparent ON grandparent.grandparentObjective = o.parent
  WHERE mo.status = 'goal' OR mo.status = 'complete' 
    OR parentStatus = 'goal' OR parentStatus = 'complete' 
    OR grandparentStatus = 'goal' OR grandparentStatus = 'complete' 
  GROUP BY o.id
```

Based on my original question the solution is not about selecting a row based on a value from an already selected row, but rather joining tables to have extra columns to check for the necessary values that come from other rows.

Comment: This solution is working, but I'm open to accepting a more elegant solution as the answer.